# Which line of code make my RSS reader to read only the bottom tags?

Tags: java, android, xml

I created XML parsing RSS reader,but it is only reading the last 3 nodes (which is title,link and description ).i want to know which lines of code making this trick(i mean reading the last nodes).if i want to read the first three nodes from this [rss site](http://www.oneindia.com/rss/news-international-fb.xml),**what i should i actually do ?** 
i am a nuwbie . can anyone post the answer as code?

```
public class HandleXML {
private String title = "title";
private String link = "link";
private String description = "description";
private String title1 = "title";
private String link1 = "link";
private String description1 = "description";
private String urlString = null;
private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

public HandleXML(String url){
    this.urlString = url;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public String getLink(){
    return link;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;

    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();

        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name=myParser.getName();

            switch (event){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    if(name.equals("title")){
                        title = text;

                    }

                    else if(name.equals("link")){
                        link = text;

                    }

                    else if(name.equals("description")){
                        description = text;

                    }

                    else{
                    }

                    break;
            }

            event = myParser.next();
        }

        parsingComplete = false;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void fetchXML(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                myparser.setInput(stream, null);

                parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                stream.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is this part of the code that is responsible to read the elements you mentioned above .

```
if(name.equals("title")){
    title = text;
}
else if(name.equals("link")){
    link = text;
}
else if(name.equals("description")){
    description = text;
}
else{
 // Write similar conditions for the other tags that you want to parse.
}
```

Comment: how can i change it ? like i want to show the first nodes, can you edit answer ?

Comment: What elements you plan to extract, we can help you here but please show us what you have got so far. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a while loop in order to process the document.
Within that loop your code reads all the title, link and description nodes.
The problem is that it overrides the variables every time, hence what you get is the last title, link and description.

If you would like to read only the firs title, link and description you could do something like:

Initialise variables like this:

```
private String title;
private String link;
private String description;
```

Than:

```
if(name.equals("title") && title != null){
    title = text;
}
else if(name.equals("link") && link != null){
    link = text;
}
else if(name.equals("description") && description != null){
    description = text;
}
```

EDIT (try this, warning: I haven't tested it)

```
public class HandleXML {
    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private String description;
    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;

    public HandleXML(String url) {
        this.urlString = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text = null;

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();

                switch (event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        if (name.equals("title") && title != null) {
                            title = text;
                        }

                        else if (name.equals("link") && link != null) {
                            link = text;
                        }

                        else if (name.equals("description") && description != null) {
                            description = text;
                        }

                        break;
                }

                event = myParser.next();
            }

            parsingComplete = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fetchXML() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);

                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: 27/07/2017 handle exception
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you edit or post the full code ?, coz i did not get you

Comment: so i should delete the while loop ? or something else